# jQuery Table Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Writing a jQuery function to test the class of a `<td>` and act accordingly. The function works by clicking the `img` inside the `<td>` and uses the class information of the `td` to test.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('td img').click(function () {
    if ((this).parent().hasClass('x')) {
        alert("Seat " + ((this).parent().attr("id")) + " is taken");
    } else if ((this).parent().hasClass('selected')){
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/a.gif');
        $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
        alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
        return false;
        } else {
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/c.gif');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
        return false;
        };
    });
});
```

The error says that the method for the image does not exist, despite me specifying the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `$` sign missing.

```
If($(this).parent()...
```

What happens here is that the click function passes the dom/html object instead of the jQuery object and thus you have to build the object with the jQuery function in order to have the correct object to work with!

Comment: Schoolboy error. I never would've spotted it either, thank you!